# I can´t read the birthday from login request facebook

Tags: android, facebook

When I enter my APP ID of Facebook the birthday data is returned, but when I change this APP ID to other the birthday data was not returned, this is my code to get the data after user login with facebook:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
loginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));

loginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.e("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                Log.d("LoginActivity", object.optString("id"));
                                Log.d("LoginActivity", object.optString("birthday"));
                                // Application code after this
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields","id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(large)");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login attempt canceled.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login attempt failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide any more details? As the question is now, it will be very difficult for anyone to provide a useful answer.

Comment: ok sure sorry for my bad english, this is my code to get the public profile data:

Comment: loginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));

Comment: all relevant info should be in your question, not in comments. please edit your question and add a lot more details.

Comment: sorry Im new in stackoverflow, I update my question with more details and the code that I use to get the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`user_birthday`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_birthday) permission requires Facebook to review it before it can be used. The exception is when the user has a role (administrator, tester, etc) in the app.

Comment: ok so this is the reason whereby I can read the birthday permision when I set my app ID because Im the admin, but when I set another APP ID I can't read the birthday because Im not the admin... So for the permission do you have a tutorial or how can I enable this, because my app only use this data to save this in my database and after that send specific information to the users that I filter in my website

Comment: You need to submit your app to Facebook for review. All the information is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: ok thanks for the answer I send my app to review, but when I check this is confuse, my app only use the birthday to save this in my database how can I show or describe this?

Comment: Just state what you use the data for? I can't possibly know what your app is for.

Comment: Ok perfect, I describe this on the app revision, thanks for help me